# How to install Ubuntu again as my previous Ubuntu 16.04 is corrupted

Tags: grub2

I am not able to install , while installing Ubuntu again at some point I got grub-efi- amd64 signed error.

Even after formatting the drive completely I got same issue.

I created a swap partition and one root partition (/) using something else option while installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing not in uefi mode. The installation asks if you want and press go back.

Comment: I didn't get you . Plz explain I new to Linux environment

Comment: in the setup(before install starts) when youre asked about UEFI click go back.

Comment: Thank you brother it's done. Can you tell me a bit what go back does. Just for knowledge

Comment: it makes the installation non UEFI, which makes the installation not go to the error. if you want to learn about UEFI just google it.